# how to get the id of asp textbox in jQuery function

Tags: jquery, validation

How can I get the id of the current asp text box in the called function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtNumeric.ClientID %>").focusout(function () {
            var textvalue = $("#<%=txtNumeric.ClientID %>").val();
            if (!validateDecimal(textvalue))
                return false;
            else {
                $(this).removeClass("focus");
                return true;
            }
        });
    });

    function validateDecimal(value) {
        var RE = new RegExp(/^\d\d*\.\d\d$/);
        if (RE.test(value)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Please Enter in XX.XX format !");
            $(this).addClass("focus");// this keyword is not working here !!
            $(this).focus(); // this keyword is not working here !!
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not pass it as a parameter?

Comment: I tend to use a class and find using that, it avoids having to mix server code with client script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass control object also in function like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtNumeric.ClientID %>").focusout(function () {
            var textvalue = $("#<%=txtNumeric.ClientID %>").val();
            if (!validateDecimal(textvalue,this))
                return false;
            else {
                $(this).removeClass("focus");
                return true;
            }
        });

    });

    function validateDecimal(value,ControlObject) {
            var RE = new RegExp(/^\d\d*\.\d\d$/);
            if (RE.test(value)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                alert("Please Enter in XX.XX format !");
                $(ControlObject).addClass("focus");// this keyword is not working here !!
                $(ControlObject).focus(); // this keyword is not working here !!
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass it as a parameter to the validateDecimal, e.g. -

```
function validateDecimal(value, textbox) {
    var RE = new RegExp(/^\d\d*\.\d\d$/);
    if (RE.test(value)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Please Enter in XX.XX format !");
        textbox.addClass("focus");
        textbox.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

With that being said, I don't think that validateDecimal should have any logic to change textbox. The reason is that each function should do only 1 thing and validateDecimal should only do the validation and return true/false. The logic to change the textbox class/etc should be in another function outside of validateDecimal.